# is there a way to pass the path for the normalized images extracted to a custom skill

Tags: azure-cognitive-search, azure-cognitive-services

For passing the parameters to the custom skill I can pass /document/normalizedimages/*/data to pass the image to my skill – is there a similar way to send the path where the image is stored (along with the image name)

Other question – if all I want is to extract images from the document – can I just have a simple indexer with no skills and just have the imageaction defined

Comment: Anuj, make sure you make you question title short and sweet, also try body of question to explain as much as possible or the best can you do is, let other know what approach you tried, so the community can solve is further!! hope this would help you further in the stackoverflow journey.

Comment: Anuj,  What do you want to do with the URL passed to the custom skill?  The answer here will depend how it is used.

Comment: want to extract the path of the input document e.g. if the input document in the blob was containerA\FolderB\FolderC\documentXYZ.pdf - i want the containerA, FolderB, FolderC along with the document name documentXYZ.pdf in my custom skill  -- since the path of the document is base64 encoded and a folder with that encoded string is created for the extracted images - i want to foldername i.e. path of the image extracted in my custom skill